Low with ta.lowest
I can't get the LOW value of the lowest candle. Is this a problem because I don't have a paid subscription?
thanks
//@version=5
indicator("test philou 10.10.2024", overlay=true)

var float lowest_0 = na

lowest_idx = ta.lowestbars(low,300)  // Trouver la bougie la plus basse
highest_idx = ta.highestbars(high, 300)  // Trouver la bougie la plus haute
lowest_0 := low[lowest_idx]

table_id = table.new(position.top_right, 2, 31, border_width = 1, border_color = color.gray)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id, 0, 0, text="lowest_idx", bgcolor=#4660c0)
    table.cell(table_id, 1, 0, text=str.tostring(lowest_idx))
    table.cell(table_id, 0, 1, text="highest_idx", bgcolor=#4660c0)
    table.cell(table_id, 1, 1, text=str.tostring(highest_idx))
    table.cell(table_id, 0, 2, text="lowest_0", bgcolor=#4660c0)
    table.cell(table_id, 1, 2, text=str.tostring(lowest_0))

I can't get the LOW value of the lowest candle. Is this a problem because I don't have a paid subscription?

No, it´s not because of your subscription. Your code causes a runtime error in line 8:

Line 8 is lowest_0 := low[lowest_idx] and this function only accepts positive values, but ta.lowestbars() returns an OFFSET, a negative number.
I changed line 8 and added a minus sign: lowest_0 := low[-lowest_idx] and the script compiles without error.
I tried it on the TSLA chart on a 2 minute timeframe. The lowest value is $214.38, which corresponds with the lowest value on the chart.
This is your table:

